# Is $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(xt)}{1+t^2}dt$ differentiable in $x\not= 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

a) Is $$F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(xt)}{1+t^2}dt$$  differentiable in $x \not= 0$?

b) What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x)$?

c) What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(x)}{x}$?

I wanted to prove that the function is differentiable by the Fundamental Theorem of the calculus. Thus when $$\frac{\arctan(xt)}{1+t^2}$$ is continuous but this is everywhere? So I do not know if I am allowed to do this.

Further I wanted to calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x)$. When we bring the limit in the integral we get $\arctan(\frac{\pi}{2}t)$, but I do not know which theorem I can use to justify that I can bring the limit inside the integral.

The last part of the question I need to calculate  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(x)}{x}$. I wanted to use the rule of l'hopital but then I get $$\frac{1}{(1+(xt)^2)(1+t^2)}$$ but then I do not know how to go further. I tried to calculate this further but then I could not solve the integral properly. I did think that it may have something to do with the fact that $t\rightarrow \infty$ but that is just a thought.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can differentiate $F$ by differentiating under the integral sign. Just check that the conditions are satisfied for it.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{y\to \infty} \arctan (y)=\frac \pi 2$.  So for every fixed value of $t$ other than $0$,  as $x\to \infty$,  the $\arctan$ goes to $\pi 2$.

Comment: @Gary When I differentiate under the integral I do not prove that it is differentiable or did you mean something else? That  is why I wanted the use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: See https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{y\to \infty} \arctan (y)=\frac \pi 2$.  So for every fixed value of $t$ other than $0$,  as $x\to \infty$,  the $\arctan$ goes to $\frac \pi 2$. You can then integrate the function inside to get $\frac \pi 2 \arctan t$.  then plugging in your limits gets you to $(\frac \pi 2)^2$ (We can ignore the value at $t=0$ because integrals don't care about changing the values on finite points, or countable, or measure 0)

Comment: What do you use to justify bringing the limit inside the integral?

Comment: Everything's continuous, so limits interchange.